# nested require_once with absolute path not working

Tags: php, debugging

I have a triple nested `require_once`:

```
user@mybox:/tmp/foo $ cat bar.php 
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'foo3.php';

user@mybox:/tmp/foo $ cat foo3.php 
<?php

require_once 'foo2.php';
echo "foo3" . PHP_EOL;

user@mybox:/tmp/foo $ cat foo2.php 
<?php

require_once 'foo.php';
echo "foo2" . PHP_EOL;

user@mybox:/tmp/foo $ cat foo.php 
<?php

require_once 'Mage.php';

echo "foo" . PHP_EOL;

user@mybox:/tmp/foo $ cat Mage.php 
<?php

die('require once works' . PHP_EOL);
```

This works: When calling `php bar.php` I get the output `require once works`.

If I now change `foo.php` to use the absolute path:

```
user@mybox:/tmp/foo $ cat foo.php
<?php

require_once '/tmp/foo/Mage.php';

echo "foo" . PHP_EOL;
```

I get the following output:

```
user@mybox:/tmp/foo $ php bar.php 
foo
foo2
foo3
```

And the include of the last file does not work.

A non-nested `require_once` also works:

```
user@mybox:/tmp/foo $ php foo.php 
require once works
```

This only happens on some machines (with identical PHP version PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Aug  6 2014 05:09:45)

*update*

```
php foo2.php
```

is also not working

Comment: Just did a quick test with foo2.php, foo.php, Mage.php and here it works. Tested with PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 (web) and PHP 5.6.2-1 (cli). Strange...

Comment: I could not replicate the issue (but I only have PHP 5.3.19 at my disposal at the moment).
Would be nice to add `error_reporting(-1);` to bar.php (just to make sure).You can also try printing the result of [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) - again, just to make sure.
Would also be interesting to see if using only absolute paths works for you (in which case, using `dirname(__FILE__)` to make relative paths absolute might solve any issue you might have).

Comment: We found out that using only absolute paths works. The mix seems to be the problem.

Comment: This question should be closed as non reproducible and deleted

Answer (score -1):

We found out that using only absolute paths works. The mix seems to be the problem.