# php undefined variable or cannot redeclare class message inside included file

Tags: php, class

I'm quit new in `PHP` and `MySQL` i'm trying to develop an practice site. But i am facing some trouble. This site is most useful for me so after lot of trying i decided to ask here.

my problem is that i have made Partially separated file for header, footer, side bar and include those file inside the index, product or etc. file. when i try to fetch database result from index.php it's work fine but i also have to make category id in sidebar.php which should be also fetch from database.

when i tying to fetch data in index.php work fine but in sidebar.php when i am trying to fetch data it warn me undefined variable when i include database class also in sidebar.php it warn me cannot redeclare class databse. there is my code and folder structure.

note: about my knowledge included initialize.php index.php at very begging and after that include header.php so it should use initialize.php but i have tried with include initialize also in sidebar.php but it generate error "cannot redeclare class database". when i remove this initialize from sidebar.php it generate error "undefined variable connection"... 
when i working is single file i mean i remove sidebar.php and write hole code direct inside index.php than it works fine.

My Folder Structure Like That.

```
| Practice_site
|---| includes
|---|---| class
|---|---|---| database.class.php
|---|---|---| validation.class.php
|---|---|---| upload.class.php
|---|---| functions.php
|---|---| initialize.php
|---| public
|---|---| site_template
|---|---|---| header.php
|---|---|---| footer.php
|---|---|---| sidebar.php
|---|---| index.php
|---|---| about.php
|---|---| products.php
|---|---| product_detail.php
|---|---| cart.php
```

`in Databse.class.php file`

```
class Database
{
private $connection;
private $error;
private $stmt;
// Set options
private $options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);

public function __construct($host,$dbname,$uname,$dbpassword="")
{
    try{
        $dns = "mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbname;
        $this->connection = new pdo($dns,$uname,$dbpassword,$this->options);    
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }

    (isset($this->error))? die("<h3>".$this->error."</h3>"):null;
}

public function query($sql)
{
    return $this->connection->query($sql);
}

public function fetch()
{
    return $this->connection->fetch();
}

public function rowCount()
{
    return $this->connection->rowCount();
}

public function fetchAll()
{
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

}//end class
$connection = new Database('localhost','dbname','user','password');
```

`in function.php file`

`in header.php file`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title or the page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include "sidebar.php"; ?>
```

`in initialize.php file`

```
<?php 
defined('DS')? null: define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT')? null: define('SITE_ROOT', 'C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'OnlineStore');
defined('LIB') ? null : define('LIB', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

include LIB.DS."class".DS."Database.class.php";
include LIB.DS."functions.php";
?>
```

`in sidebar.php file`

```
try{
    require "../includes/initialize.php";  // when remove this line php generate undefined variable connection else generate error cannot redeclare class databas line 9
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY position";
    $categories = $connection->query($sql);
}catch(EXCEPTION $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

<?php while ( $category = $categories->fetch() ): ?>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $category['category']; ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

`in index.php file`

```
<?php 
try{
    // require "../includes/initialize.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC";
    $products = $connection->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY position";
    $categories = $connection->query($sql);

}catch(EXCEPTION $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
include "header.php";

<?php while( $row = $products->fetch() ): ++$counter ?>
<div class="product_box <?php echo ( ($counter%3)===0 ) ? 'no_margin_right' : '' ?>">
    <h3><?php echo htmlentities($row['product_name']) ?></h3>
    <a href="productdetail.php"><img src="images/products_img/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>" alt="Shoes 3" /></a>
    <p><?php echo htmlentities(substr($row['description'], 0,100)) ?></p>
  <p class="product_price">$ 60</p>
    <a href="shoppingcart.php" class="addtocart"></a>
    <a href="productdetail.php" class="detail"></a>
</div>   
<?php echo ( ($counter%3)===0 ) ? '<div class="cleaner"></div>' : '' ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: why no just include the initialize class in the index.php and not in the sidebar?

Comment: about my knowledge included initialize.php index.php at very begging and after that include header.php so it should use initialize.php but i have tried with include initialize also in sidebar.php but it generate error "cannot redeclare class database". when i remove this initialize from sidebar.php it generate error "undefined variable connection"...

Comment: That's pretty useful info; consider adding it to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) and [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php).

Also, note [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885077/nested-require-once-with-absolute-path-not-working) and its comments, as it may be a problem here as well.

Comment: in both file?? sidebar and index page?

Comment: @arif Yes, try in both on them.

Comment: yes @tomasz Zieleskeiwicz i have tried both of them but when i do so it generate error "cannot redeclare class Database."

Comment: functions.php is empty?

Comment: no there is also some function. like redirect_to(), layout_include(), escape() etc

Comment: I have reproduced Your problem. require_once "../includes/initialize.php" in index.php and sidebar.php solved the problem for me. Check function.php for require or include.
And one more thing - try using absolute or relative path in ALL includes. I think there is some king of issue with that in PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65076/discussion-between-arif-and-tomasz-zieleskeiwicz).